# Sci-fi story where humans first help alien life advance and then lead factions to war against each other

Tags: identification-request

I've been trying to find a story I've read about 20 years ago, without success. It is about a group of human astronauts landing on an alien planet, where they help the local life advance technologically and socially, but eventually they break into factions led by the different humans, who go to war against each other. It was humorous and I feel like I've read it in my "classical sci-fi writers" phase, so nothing too modern, let's say up to the 80s. Almost certainly American.

It was humorous but not an outright parody. The aliens were not humanoid, if I remember well, at all, were all of the same species (and same society, I believe). The humans arrived as a single crew of a human spacecraft. Not sure if they were friendly, but they definitely grew apart. I don't have any memory of the cover art, but I think it was a classic sci-fi paperback - bad paper, pocket format, colourful cover. I don't think any of the humans was treated as a main character and they were not very detailed.

Comment: Humorous warlike aliens? Sort of like the *Hoka* stories but different?

Comment: Possible questions to help narrow it down: Were the aliens humanoid or radically non-human? Were there many types of aliens? Were the humans already factionalized? Do you remember anything about the cover art? Was there a main protagonist, or an ensemble, and what were those characters like?

Comment: It might be Jem by Frederik Pohl, but without further detail it could be dozens of other books too.

Comment: It was humorous but not an outright parody.

The aliens were not humanoid, if I remember well, at all, were all of the same species (and same society, I believe).

The humans arrived as a single crew of a human spacecraft. Not sure if they were friendly, but they definitely grew apart.

I don't have any memory of the cover art, but I think it was a classic sci-fi paperback - bad paper, pocket format, colourful cover.

I don't think any of the humans was treated as a main character and they were not very detailed.

Comment: It was far less serious than Jem sounds, but that's definitely going on my reading list, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail @vsvec! Could you possibly edit it into the question itself? It will be clearer there than in the comments, where it can get lost.

Comment: ome aspects of the description had me thinking of *Lord of Light* by Zelazney, but that is cleanly not a match. For one thing the PoV chractersm are mostly human.